# Change Highcharts xAxis step value on chart redraw event?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart. I want to change the xAxis step value when ever the chart redraw happened. I have the following code in HighCharts

```
                   events: {
                        redraw: function () {                            
                            this.xAxis[0].update({
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

How to update the value ?

Comment: So, you want to update axis in redraw event. But you know that update() will call redraw()? I hope you got my point - infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ofqp34u3/

Whenever you add new series, xAxis tickInterval gets updated.

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
     tickInterval: 3
})
```

Set event:redraw function as

```
 chart: {    
        events: {
            redraw: function () {
                var label = this.renderer.label('The chart was just redrawn', 100, 120)
                    .attr({
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        padding: 10,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 8
                    })
                    .css({
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    })
                    .add();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    label.fadeOut();
                }, 1000);

            }
        }
    },
```